# SQL Server Job - RunAs for T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, ssms

I am trying to create make a user Credential appear in RunAs when I select T-SQL as my job step. However, the user account didn't appear.

Following the steps here, I managed to create RunAs but when I select T-SQL, it didn't show up.

Create Credentials for our Windows Service Account
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-credential?view=sql-server-ver15

Assign Job Run As at Step Level.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/configure-a-user-to-create-and-manage-sql-server-agent-jobs?view=sql-server-ver15

Can't find any T-SQL in the subsystem
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-grant-proxy-to-subsystem-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Any ideas on how I can get RunAs appear in T-SQL ? Under Proxies, how can I add new SubSystem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can add subsystems to the list of Proxies.

SQL Agent hasn't really had any love in quite sometime, so while Run As appears as a dropdown option when you first create a step with the default T-SQL command type, if you cycle to something else and then back to T-SQL you will see Run As is no longer an option (it's grayed out).

This means T-SQL will be executed as the Service Account that the Agent service runs under...

...Unless you [impersonate another user!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: After much testing, I found that it is easier to call a SQL script using CMD prompt in the SQL Server job where I can assign RunAs. 

Check sqlcmd